# rw expression IN expression

Tags: lean

Say, I need:

```
rw ← nat.mul_one (d+d),
```

But there are multiple (d+d) in the whole goal. Can I do something like:

```
rw ← nat.mul_one (d+d) in (5+(d+d)),
```

so that (d+d) is rewritten only where the full expression in parentheses is 5+(d+d) is matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `mathlib`'s `nth_rewrite`, or `rw`'s optional `occs` argument. For example:

if `⊢ (d + d) + 5 * (d + d) + 2 * (d + d) = 8 * (d + d)`, then `nth_rewrite ←nat.mul_one (d +  d) 1` should work, as should `rw ←nat.mul_one (d + d) { occs := occurrences.pos [2]}` (note that `nth_rewrite` is zero-indexed whilst `rw` is 1-indexed).

You can also mess around with `conv`, but I don't recommend that; something that would work for the above example with `conv` is `conv { congr, congr, congr, skip, rw ←nat.mul_one (d + d) }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can either learn about the joys of `conv` mode [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/extras/conv.html), which enable you to do targetted rewriting, or you can use the `nth_rewrite` tactic documented [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#nth_rewrite%20/%20nth_rewrite_lhs%20/%20nth_rewrite_rhs) which will let you choose precisely which of the `d+d`s you want to change.